# Method return giving error and zero-arguments constructor done wrong

Tags: java, methods

I am writing this small program as an assignment and I am stuck at 2 things, 1st I am not that good with zero arguments constructors as its a new concept for me for now, 2nd in the last method 'Check' the return is giving error :" Syntax error on token "return", void expected". 
If you can help with the zero arguments constructor by correcting it and the return by pointing the mistake it would much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Zeller {
   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
private int year ;
private int month;
private int day;
private float weekDay;
  int countLeapYears;


        public Zeller() {
            year = 0;
            month = -1;
            day = -1;
        }
        public static int setYear( int year ){
            if(year > 0){
                return year;
            }
            else return year;
        }
        public static int setMonth( int month ){
            if( month >= 1 && month <= 12){
                return month;
            }
            else return -1;
        }
        public static int setDay( int day ){
            if( day >=1 && day <= 31){
                return day;
            }
            else return -1;
        }
        public static void Check ( int year, int month, int day ){
            year = setYear(year);
            month = setMonth(month);
            day = setDay(day);
            return year, month, day;
        } 
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
       Zeller ex1 = new Zeller();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't return something from a method with return type void. If you wanted to simply end the method you could write `return;` and the method would be ended. You also can't return 3 different values like that from a method, you'd need to combine them into a larger object. As for your issue with the zero-argument constructor, what functionality are you trying to add to it that's giving you trouble?

Comment: `public Zeller()` is the zero-arg constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your constructor.  I do not understand your confusion about zero-argument constructors.

As a comment stated, you are attempting to return a value when your method declaration states that it does not return anything (void).  Also, the return value with commas does not work.  You can only return one thing, although that thing can be an array or an object that has multiple values.  An array would be something like `new int[] {year, month, day};`.

You don't mention it, but you may also be trying to access member variables from a static method.  Static methods are not methods on an instantiated object.  If you intended `Check()` to reference the private member variables at the top of the class, then it should not be static.  Also, if you are intending to access the member variables, since you are overloading the variable names `year`, `month`, and `day`, you will need to use `this.year`, etc., to reference the member variables instead of your formal parameters.

Comment: thank you for your reply thats exactly what confused me with zero-argument constructors, i checked for answers and everyone was doing something different some didnt put 'this' and others did use it so i got confused. 
For the method i then changed it to int and trying to figure out if i should use arrays or just return with keeping the method type void. Any ideas what would that do or how different it is ?

Comment: It's really a matter of style. Objects are generally meant to encapsulate data, i.e. the members of the class, and to marhall functionality on that data to the same place, i.e. the methods of the class.  So you might ask yourself, what data do I want this class to represent?  Secondarily, you might ask yourself, what functionality do I want regarding (using, manipulating) that data?  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add getter methods to your class to get the data members seperately.
2. Inside your Check method, instead of using primitive int type, you can use Integer references for getting values at the same time if you really need this.